# Deserialize XML Elements Return null 3

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have looked at several other questions for this same issue but have not been able to resolve my problem. I have classes, code, and XML as follows. However, after the Deserialize call my type variable contains a TestList array which contains a TestElement but the TestElement is null. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TestXMLSerialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestRootElement));
            string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><TestRootElement><TestList><TestItem><TestElement>Test Data</TestElement></TestItem></TestList></TestRootElement>";
            TestRootElement type = (TestRootElement)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));

            Console.WriteLine(type.TestList[0].TestElement);
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("TestRootElement")]
    public class TestRootElement
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("TestList")]
        public List<TestItem> TestList { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("TestItem")]
    public class TestItem
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("TestElement")]
        public string TestElement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have too many `XmlRoot` attributes - a document has **one** root, in this case `TestRootElement`.

Comment: Thanks @Oded. However, that does not seem to be the issue. I have corrected the code to use XmlType but still get a null value for TestElement.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the code works fine without any Serialization attributes.

```
public class TestRootElement
{
    public List<TestItem> TestList { get; set; }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public string TestElement { get; set; }
}
```

So adding the attributes back in one at a time I found that the List<> needed an XmlArray attribute instead of XmlElement.

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("TestRootElement")]
public class TestRootElement
{
    [XmlArray("TestList")]
    public List<TestItem> TestList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlType("TestItem")]
public class TestItem
{
    [XmlElement("TestElement")]
    public string TestElement { get; set; }
}
```